# Interrupt Nokogiri SAX Parser?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I'm using a Nokogiri SAX parser to find a specific fragment in an XML document, but once I'm done there's no reason to continue scanning the document.

Is there a way to immediately terminate parsing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looking through the source code for Nokogiri, I do not *believe* this is possible.

Nokogiri would, at some point—in response to some Ruby method or return value—need to call [`xmlStopParser()`](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-parser.html#xmlStopParser) in libxml2. Because:

1. I do not see this function anywhere in [the source code](https://github.com/tenderlove/nokogiri) (including the source code for [`xml_sax_parser.c`](https://github.com/tenderlove/nokogiri/blob/master/ext/nokogiri/xml_sax_parser.c)), and
2. I do not find any hits when Googling for ["Nokogiri" "xmlStopParser"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22xmlStopParser%22+%22nokogiri%22)

I have come to the conclusion that Nokogiri does not currently have any way to stop parsing.

Comment: Could you kludge it with an exception? That would be pretty nasty, an abuse of the exception system, and I should do some sort of penance for even thinking of it.

Comment: @muistooshort You horrible, horrible man. +1 for the idea, though. :) Still, I'd be a little worried that it _might_ leave some memory leaking out of the ears of the libxml2 SAX parser which may never have been able to `ensure` that it cleaned up.

Comment: It does work but I'm too ashamed to put it down as an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the investigation Phrogz! I guess I'll just let it parse the entire document, and do a few more sanity checks while I'm at it. @muistooshort -- I did in fact consider doing that as well xD.

Comment: Extending on the exception idea, using `throw :obscured_symbol_919155` and `catch :obscured_symbol_919155` seems less sinful. (Or create a unique token using `Object.new`)